# Memory leak which does not appear when running with CLRProfiler

Tags: .net, oracle, memory, memory-leaks, profiler

I have an extremely annoying problem. Out project runs as a Windows Service on a Windows Server 2012 R2 system. It's a fully managed application, processing some data files to gather measurement statistics, etc.

I have a memory leak somewhere, which I confirmed with Perfmon: I can see the Gen2 heap growing slowly but surely. After a half to one hour, the application crashes.

I've put together a console application to host the same application just to have more control and to exclude the service stuff. Same things happened there.
Then I started the console application with CLRProfiler, and I didn't believe my eyes when I saw that memory usage is nice and low all the time, while the exact same files were being processed!

What more, the memory leak doesn't appear in our current dev environment, only in the production. The only difference now is that the production version uses Oracle.ManagedDataAccess data provider, and the dev version uses MySQL. Even if the managed Oracle provider had some bug or any issue, it's still crazy that when running with the profiler I can't see anything.

The application is very complex, really hard, almost hopeless to find the leak without the help of the profiler. I'm disappointed, hope anyone can suggest something which could save the day. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would appear that you need to change your development environment so it uses the same tech stack as your production environment. From your statements above it appears that it's not a CLR issue as the CLR profiler doesn't show any memory loss; therefore it's something outside the CLR, and it seems likely that it's something related to the database in use unless there are other tech stack differences which have not been mentioned. Best of luck.

Comment: Is console app also crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it turned out that infact it was leaking with CLRProfiler as well, but much slower, probably the whole execution was slower due to constant profiling. That's why I didn't notice it. I had to run it over on hour to realize the leak.

It seems like infact there is an issue in the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess driver, at least in the version I'm using (a quite old one). The leak seems to be caused by unreleased OracleParameter objects. I'm gonna try the latest version, and I really hope it's already fixed, because using the unmanaged ODP.NET was one of my worst nightmares in my carreer.

Thanks for everyone's time who tried to help.

UPDATE:
For future readers, I can confirm that with the latest version (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll, version 4.121.2.0) this memory leak has been solved.